# Vim Syntax: match only at the start of region - not subsequent ones

Tags: syntax, vim

I have the following Vim syntax file:

```
" Vim syntax file
" Language: ScreenplayText - the textual source of ScreenplayXML
" Maintainer: Shlomi Fish <shlomif@iglu.org.il>
" Home: http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Grammar-Screenplay/
"
" Author: Shlomi Fish
" Filenames: *.screenplay-text.txt
" Last Change: Thu Jul  3 00:59:42 IDT 2008
" Version: 0.0.1

" Thanks to Andy Wokula for his help on:
" https://groups.google.com/group/vim_use/browse_thread/thread/6c0906617d67864e/a21938c5df1d15cb?show_docid=a21938c5df1d15cb

" Quit if syntax file is already loaded
if version < 600
    syntax clear
elseif exists("b:current_syntax")
    finish
endif

syntax sync minlines=50

" syntax match screenplayTextComment /<!--\_.\{-0,}-->/
" syntax match screenplayTextDescription /^ *\[\_.\{-0,}\]/
syntax region screenplayTextComment start="<!--" end="-->"
syntax region screenplayTextDescription start="^ *\[" end="]"

" syntax region screenplayTextSaying start=/\(^\s*\n\)\@<=\_^\(+\{2,\}\|[^[:+]*\):/ end=/^\s*$/ contains=screenplayTextAddress,screenplayTextInnerDesc
syntax region screenplayTextSaying start=/\(^\s*\n\)\@<=\_^\(+\{2,\}\|[^[:+]*\):/ end=/^\s*$/ contains=screenplayTextAddress

" syntax match screenplayTextAddress /\%^\(+\{2,\}\|[^[:+]*\):/ contained nextgroup=screenplayTextInnerDesc
syntax match screenplayTextAddress /[^:]\+:/ contained nextgroup=screenplayTextSayingAfterAddress

syntax region screenplayTextSayingAfterAddress contained
" syntax match screenplayTextInnerDesc /\[\_.\{-0,}\]/ contained nextgroup=screenplayTextInnerDesc


" For debugging - remove.
" hi def link screenplayTextSaying Statement

hi def link screenplayTextComment Comment
hi def link screenplayTextDescription PreProc
hi def link screenplayTextInnerDesc PreProc
hi def screenplayTextAddress      term=bold cterm=bold gui=bold
```

It is intended for [XML-Grammar-Screenplay](http://www.shlomifish.org/open-source/projects/XML-Grammar/Fiction/), but the screenplayTextAddress still highlights stuff in subsequent lines with ":", like in:

```
Kate: Of course! See, my obsession with the Bible continued throughout my
life, and later on I became a scholar: first as a married woman who just
hanged around universities and learned things from the male professors
and students, later on as someone who helped some professors with their
research and eventually got credited, and as time progressed,
I got a B.A., and then a Ph.D., and am now a professor.
```

The second line with the ":" colon still gets highlighted. How do I prevent it from being highlighted?

Thanks for any insights.

Regards,

-- Shlomi Fish

**P.S.:** here is [the repository for the vim-screenplay-text highlighting](https://bitbucket.org/shlomif/vim-screenplay-text) (a Mercurial one on bitbucket) and here is [the screenplay I use to test it](https://github.com/shlomif/Selina-Mandrake/blob/master/selina-mandrake/screenplay/selina-mandrake-the-slayer.screenplay-text.txt) (in its GitHub git repository).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `screenplayTextSaying` group contains two branches; I'd separate them into two separate regions and then use the `matchgroup` to do the highlighting directly on the region start of the address ending with the colon. See `:help :syn-matchgroup`

```
syntax region screenplayTextSaying start=/\(^\s*\n\)\@<=\_^+\{2,\}:/ end=/^\s*$/
syntax region screenplayTextSaying end=/^\s*$/ matchgroup=screenplayTextAddress start=/\(^\s*\n\)\@<=\_^[^[:+]*:/
"syntax match screenplayTextAddress /[^:]\+:/ Not needed any more!
```

Comment: Thanks! I used a variation on that to achieve what I needed with some help from the people on Freenode's #vim. I should note that the matchgroup=... must come before the start and end. Next time, please test your code.

Comment: I explicitly placed the `matchgroup=` _after_ the `end=` so that it only applies to the following `start=`, and I did test this. Next time, please read the documentation thoroughly ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only method to recognize the first line of paragraph is that it follows a blank line.

```
" Define blank line at first
syntax match EmptyLines "\(^\s*\n\)\+" nextgroup=FistLine, Description

" Then define Fist line
syntax region FirstLine start=+^[^\<\[]+ oneline contains=Address

" Then define Address
syntax match Address "^[^<\[]+:" contained

" Description
syntax match Description "\[[^\[]+\]"

" Comment
" Comment match code

" For the rest of text, just give them a general format
```

I did not test the code, just provide a thought. Please try out by yourself. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I'm not talking about a semicolon - «;», but about a colon - «:» and furthermore, the sayer of the utterance may contain other characters aside from those matching \w such as spaces or whatever. Moreover, I don't care about not highlighting the colon itself, I just want only the ^[:]\+: in the first line to be highlighted - not the subsequent lines that contain a colon.